# How to create files argument for bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx()?

Tags: python

How to create **files** argument for example for **bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx()**?

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.import_scene.html

I have only strings - file names

Answer (score 0):

nvm:
`files = ({'name': filename},)`
works fine